# regex first occurance in whole text only

Tags: regex, perl

I searched through a lot of "regex first match only" questions but couldn't manage to build my regex based on the results. I am not good in regex, i use the following to replace all the occurrences in the text in perl:

```
$xmlText =~ s/(xmlns)/$exhangeText/g;
```

However I just want to have the first occurrence to be changed, how can I achieve this?

Many thanks for any help
Nico

Comment: Note: The capturing parens in your code are useless. `s/xmlns/$exhangeText/` would suffice (and would be faster).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the global modifier:

```
$xmlText =~ s/(xmlns)/$exhangeText/;
```

Comment: Thanks ... that was easy and somehow a punch in the face..
Will mark as the answer as soon as the 10 min are over