# Perl REGEX, only first occurrence on the same line is replaced

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following sequence of text on the same line in a file MYREGEX.txt:

```
test1.f.ABC, test2.f.XYZ, test3.f.PQR));
```

Which I would like to transform to:

```
test1.abc, test2.xyz, test3.pqr));
```

Consequently, I came up with the following Perl expression to do the needful:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/\.f\.([A-Z]*?[a-z0-9]*?)([\s\);,])/\.\L$1$2/' ./MYREGEX.txt
```

But, the script seems to replace only the first occurrence on that line as below:

```
test1.abc, test2.f.XYZ, test3.f.PQR));
```

Can someone please tell me what needs to be tweaked in my script ?

Comment: Well looks like the "g" needed to be added to the end of the pattern.. like so s/\.f\.([A-Z]*?[a-z0-9]*?)([\s\);,])/\.\L$1$2/g that seemed to have done the trick..  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: This has got to be a dupe, but I'm at a loss to actually find it.

Comment: @Sobrique I found the inverse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932072/regex-first-occurance-in-whole-text-only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `g` add the end of your regex for globally replacemant:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/\.f\.([A-Z]*?[a-z0-9]*?)([\s\);,])/\.\L$1$2/g' ./MYREGEX.txt
```

Comment: But, without the "/g", does it not default to a global replacement strategy ? What is the behavior without the "/g" ?

Comment: @TheLoneJoker [Here](https://regex101.com/r/mD6mV0/1) is the behavior without `/g`

Comment: @TheLoneJoker Default stategy is replace first occurence if you can see in your result.

Comment: So, it looks as though "perl -p -i -e " works on the stream only one line at a time.. and not "globally"..